# How to open/close a Foundation Modal or tab in TS file using typescript only(without $ to access the variable)

Tags: typescript, zurb-foundation, angular8

I am working on an angular project. To open a modal in .ts file I used JQuery method - 
1. to open a modal:
`$('#myModal').foundation('open');`
2. to close a modal : 
`$('#myModal').foundation('close');`
3. and for Tab view - to open a particular tab from .ts file I used following command:
`$("#myTabs").foundation("selectTab",$("#firstPanel"));`

How can I work on these things with pure typescript only(not using JS or jQuery)? 
Let me know if there is any alternative to it in typescript. It would be of great help to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have used foundation with jquery, I don't think so, you can do it in typescript way unless foundation provides an Angular wrapper like most of libraries framework have like bootstrap or you play with dom elements with vanilla JS (not recommended better to go with Jquery if everything is already provided by foundaiton).

[Bootstrap framework](https://getbootstrap.com/)

[Angular Wrapper for bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/)

Comment: Foundation is used with jQuery only to initialize it, $(document).foundation(); 
I don't think we should use it in any other way?

Comment: jQuery is used by many parts of Foundation, it is currently required.

Comment: @DanielRuf So currently there is no way that it can be done without using jQuery?

Comment: Exactly. jQuery is required.